# nginx: empty subdomain can not work

Tags: nginx

I read this article http://bneijt.nl/blog/post/name-based-virtual-hosting-with-nginx/
and excerpts is as follow:

```
server {
    server_name ~^((?<subdomain>.*)\.)?(?<domain>[^.]+)\.(?<tld>[^.]+)$;
    if ($subdomain = "") {
        set $subdomain "_";
    }
    location / {
        index index.html;
        root /srv/http/vhost/${domain}.${tld}/${subdomain};
    }
}
```

I imitate it and write my configuration like this:

```
server {
    server_name  ~^((?<subdomain>.*)\.)aa\.com$;
    if ($subdomain = "") {
        set $subdomain "www";
    }

    location / {
        root   /var/www/${subdomain}.aa.com/public;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

**Question:**
If input `www.aa.com`,it works,but input `aa.com`,it cann't work,domain name resolution is ok,what's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by - 'it cann't work' any errors in the nginx error log?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

**1. Create separate vhost for example.net with redirects**

```
server {
   listen *:80;
   server_name example.net;

   return 301 http://www.example.net;
}

server {
   listen *:80;

   server_name  ~^((?<subdomain>.*)\.)example\.net$;

   location / {
       root   /vhosts/${subdomain}.example.net/public_html;
       index  index.html index.htm;
   }
}
```

**2. Fix regular expression**

> server_name ~^((?<subdomain>.*)\.)?example\.net$

I have added `?` sign at the start of example

- original - https://regex101.com/r/lY5iT8/1
- modified - https://regex101.com/r/lY5iT8/2